# error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl()

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase

Hola no consigo saber cual es el problema respecto a este error, este es el fragmento de código que utilizo:

```
 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage =
                                new FriendlyMessage(null, mUsername, 
       mPhotoUrl,
                                        task.getResult().getDownloadUrl()
                                                .toString(), 
   user.getData().getID(), Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());

        mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child
       (THREAD_CHILD).child(path).child(MESSAGE_CHILD).child(key)
                          .setValue(friendlyMessage);
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Image upload task was not successful.",
                                task.getException());
                    }
```

Comment: Por favor explica qué es lo que intentas hacer y pon en la pregunta la traza completa del error. Gracias.

Comment: `task.getResult()`devuelve un objeto que no contiene ningun método `getDownloadUrl()`

Comment: El codigo es ilegible, podrias poner bien lo que quieres hacer acompañado de un codigo formateado y completo ? gracias

Answer (score 0):

Si tu intencion es subir una foto o archivo a Firebase Storage , obtener la url y ponerla en el database deberias hacer lo siguiente

```
  //En este caso guardamos la foto en el storage bajo la siguiente direccion -- fotos -- userUID -- nombre de la foto tomada
StorageReference fileReference = mStorageReference.child("fotos").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(filePath.getLastPathSegment());
fileReference.putFile(filePath).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    //Devolvemos la url de descarga
                    return mStorageReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        //Obtenemos la url descarga
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        Log.e(TAG, "onComplete: Success " );
                        //La ponemos en el database
                       mFirebaseDatabaseReference.child
   (THREAD_CHILD).child(path).child(MESSAGE_CHILD).child(key)
                      .setValue(friendlyMessage);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "upload failed: " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Este codigo te va a servir para subir una foto a tu Storage, obtener el link de descarga y ponerlo en alguna referencia en tu Database. Como vi en tu pregunta, retornas un mensajes que la foto no se pudo cargar, asi que debes estar haciendo eso.

donde `mStorageReference` es

```
StorageReference mStorageReference;
mStorageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
```